# java class types - what do they mean?

Tags: java, types

What is the java `class` type used for?  I am confused about what it means and how it is different than declaring an `object` type:

```
Class className;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are several uses for a Class object.  For example, say I want to create an instance of a class based on some class name stored in a config file.

```
String className = config.myClass;
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
Object myClassInstance = clazz.newInstance();
```

Comment: Is this instance created using reflection?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the definition of reflection is.  I've always thought of it as asking a class about itself.  For example, once you get the Class object for a class you can then ask for a list of its methods and fields.  You can even invoke one of its methods.  The Class.getDeclaredMethods object returns you a Method instance that you can call "invoke" on.

Comment: Yes, that is reflection. The java.lang.Class object gives access to all reflection methods.

Answer (score 3):

It represents the **runtime type** of the object. The actual programmatic use of the `Class` type is often found in [reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/) and [generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf).

For example, loading a JDBC driver abstractly with help of `Class#forName()`:

```
String jdbcDriverClassName = getItFromSomeExternalConfigurationFile();
Class.forName(jdbcDriverClassName);
```

Or typecasting an generic `Object` to a beforeknown type:

```
public static <T> T findAttribute(String key, Class<T> type) {
    return type.cast(attributeMap.get(key)); // It's a Map<String, Object>.
}
```

...which can be used as

```
SomeType instance = findAttribute("someKey", SomeType.class);
```

A more extended example can be found [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/08/generic-object-converter.html) in flavor of a "generic object converter".

Actually, reading the [`java.lang.Class`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) javadoc, including all of the available methods, should give you an idea what it can be used for.

Comment: Wtf was that downvote about? :D C'mon, leave a comment so that we can discuss and learn with/from each other.

Answer (score 2):

`Class` is a special type of `Object`, i.e `Class` is a sub class of `Object`. Every class you define has its own `Class` object. You can access this as `MyObject.class` or `myInstance.getClass()`. In another word, any class you define has a `Class` attribute where as any class is an `Object`. I agree it is slightly confusing to a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

[javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) says:

> Instances of the class Class represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application. An enum is a kind of class and an annotation is a kind of interface. Every array also belongs to a class that is reflected as a Class object that is shared by all arrays with the same element type and number of dimensions. The primitive Java types (boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double), and the keyword void are also represented as Class objects.
>
> Class has no public constructor. Instead Class objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method in the class loader.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it when checking the type of some variable or check for inheritance runtime.
It's also used in reflection, to load dynamically types and execute methods on them.

Answer (score 1):

From the book [Thinking in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486):

> **The Class object**
>
> To understand how Run Time Type Information (RTTI) works in Java, you must first know how type information is represented at run time. This is accomplished through a
>   special kind of object called the Class object, which contains information
>   about the class. In fact, the Class object is used to create all of the
>   'regular' objects of your class.